# Export HTML table as excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blob

I am currently generating html table on the UI and I wanted the same to exported as excel. I have tried from many resources, but unsuccessful.

Can someone please suggest how to proceed with this?

Comment: please check this https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/ .Hope this helps.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, I used the same , excel is generating but there is only cell with data and data is like this <thead....